# Making a sprite with a submit button in a table

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sprite

I want to create two sprite buttons to validate (or not) some requests.

So here is my **agreed button** :

```rb
<div class="validation_button loan_button" id="agreed_loan_button_<%=loan.id%>">
  <% if loan.agreed == true %>
    <div class="icon-agree enabled"></div>
  <% elsif loan.agreed == false %>
    <div class="icon-agree disabled"></div>
  <% else %>
    <%= form_for(loan, remote: true) do |f| %>
      <div><%= f.hidden_field :agreed, value: true %></div>
      <%= image_submit_tag("24px.png", alt: t('button.loan.agree'), title: t('button.loan.agree'), class: "icon-agree active") %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Where 24px.png is a 24px side size square transparent image.

And here is where my agree button takes place :

```rb
<table class="table table-hover">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th><%= t('product.borrower') %></th>
      <th><%= t('loan.created.since_the') %></th>
      <th><%= t('loan.validation') %></th>
    </tr>
    <% @pending_loans.each do |loan| %>
      <tr id="loan_<%= loan.id %>">
        <td>
          <%= link_to loan.seeker.name, loan.seeker %>
        </td>
        <td>
         <%= I18n.l loan.created_at, format: :only_date %>
        </td>
        <td class="validation">
          <%= render 'loans/buttons/agreed', loan: loan %>
          <%= render 'loans/buttons/refused', loan: loan %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then here is my **css** :

```css
.icon-agree {
  background: url("agree.png");
  display: block;
  width: 24px;

  height: 24px;
  &.enabled {
    background-position: 0 -24px;
  }
  &.disabled {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  &.active {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    &:hover {
      background-position: 0 -24px;
    }
    &:active {
      background-position: 0 -48px;
    }
  }
}
```

When I using my app in a development environment, it renders exactly what I want. But if I push it to production, the square transparent image becomes blank and hide the sprite background.

Do you have an idea to make this works, and make it more... good practice ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using SASS/SCSS. Have you verified that your SCSS files are properly compiled in production? Are you using anything (e.g., Compass) to assemble your sprites?

Comment: Yes, I'm using SASS/SCSS. How can I verify that my SCSS files are properly compiled in production ?

Comment: Have a look at the CSS files that are output. You could diff those with your CSS files from development and see if there are any obvious issues. Also, make sure you understand the differences in the runtime envinronments with [Rails' Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets)

Comment: Thanks but I don't know how to look at the outputed CSS files. Can you tell me how to do it ?

Comment: Where the files are stored in your application's file system depends on how you have your application configured, but at the very least you should be able to see them from your browser. Either use your browser's developer tools or simply view the page source, look for the stylesheet includes and view them from there.

Comment: Ok, it seems to be good, here what I saw `.icon-agree{background:url("agree.png");display:block;width:24px;height:24px}.icon-agree.enabled{background-position:0 -24px}.icon-agree.disabled{background-position:0 0}.icon-agree.active{text-indent:-9999px}.icon-agree.active:hover{background-position:0 -24px}.icon-agree.active:active{background-position:0 -48px}`
It seems a nice compilation of my SCSS...

Comment: Note the path to the image (`background: url("agree.png");`). Does this resolve correctly, or does it generate a 404? Check to see that you're not getting any exceptions in your browser's developer console.

Comment: It resolve correctly. I even downloaded it, and it the right transparent square. And when I right click 'information about the image', I can see the background image is seen, but it's not displayed, and it had no size (0px 0px)...