# Making a sprite with a delete button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css-sprites

I have a delete button method in my helper :

```rb
def product_delete_link(product)
  link_to t('product.delete'), product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: t('confirm.sure') }
end
```

I surround it with a div class "button_delete_product" in my view :

```rb
<h1>
  <%= @product.name %>
  <span class="button_delete_product">
    <%= product_delete_link(@product) if admin_or_owner(@product) %>
  </span>
</h1>
```

Then I define a sprite in my SCSS :

```rb
h1 {
  .button_delete_product {
    background: url("corbeille40px.png");
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    &:hover {
      background-position: 0 -40px;
    }
    &:active {
      background-position: 0 -80px;
    }
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work as expected. I do have my sprite, but it is not linked to the delete method, so nothing happens when I click on it. Do you know how to solve it ?

Comment: This is not rails related. Could you post your resulting html ?

Comment: I assume you mean that your sprite is not working correctly? Try putting it on the a tag and not the span. If the delete button isnt doing anything, make sure you have the rails jquery

Comment: I have the rails jquery. I found a way to circumvent this, but it works only in development, not in production : I replaced `t('product.delete')` by `image_tag('transparent.png')` that is a transparent image with same size as the sprite, and I removed `text-indent` in my CSS to make the link come back where it belonged...
But as I said, in production, the transparent image is blank displayed, so the sprite that is under can not be seen. I have [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17471653/making-a-sprite-with-a-submit-button-in-a-table)